# Android: android textview recognition

Tags: android, android-layout

This code is within a method in a class (not main):
TextView moodouttw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moodouttw);

The textview seemes not to be recognized in this part: R.id.moodouttw

The textview moodouttw is located within a layout xml.

Can someone please helpout with code to correctly format the code above?
(I've tried to minimize code at first if it could be solved with any further info)

LOGCAT: 940Kb cant post

Comment: Can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

is not `iR.d` is just `R.id`

the proper way will be

```
findViewById(R.id.moodouttw);
```

this is the complete correct sentence

```
TextView moodouttw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moodouttw);
```

ok as you stated at your xml file, the problem is that your `TextView` id is moodtw   and you are doing R.id.moodouttw;

so you need to do this

TextView moodouttw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moodtw);

Comment: hi, sorry its a typo

Comment: with a clean project sometimes the R problems just solve, try build - clean project

Comment: can you share the xml of the TextView ?

Comment: can you also compile your project and tell me the logcat error ?

Comment: ok the problem is that your textview id is moodtw  and you are passing R.id.moodouttw   ... so the correct one will be R.id.moodtw;

Comment: errormsg: Error:(19, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable moodouttw

Comment: But just copy and paste the first 10 lines of the logcat, you are posting innacurate question, is difficult to help this way

Comment: sorry, got diisturbance , here is the xml file:

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moodtw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sleeptw"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sleeptw"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sleeptw"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick= "mood"
        android:text="@string/unhappyness_depondency"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: So just do what I edited in my answer change after R.id. the right name

Comment: here is the xml file with the textfield I try to change:

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/moodouttw"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/moodtw"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/moodtw"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anxietyouttw"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/anxietyouttw"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="14sp" />